# NServiceBus subscribers without a local message queue - is this possible?

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I want to create a desktop client app that listens to an NServiceBus. The client has no rights on the local machine, so no local message queue access. It doesn't matter if the client misses some messages. Is it possible to have an NServiceBus subscriber without a local MSMQ?

Comment: Is it not an option to use another transport on the client perhaps?

Comment: Have you considered making it a browser app and then using SignalR for notifications?

Comment: There is also a .NET client library for SignalR, so you could use it within your desktop client app to maintain a persistent connection with a server.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible (see here: http://nservicebus.uservoice.com/forums/24334-general/suggestions/315106-support-msmq-4-0-remote-input-queue)

And not only is is not possible, it's a highly unorthodox approach. If you want to participate in messaging you must extend the queuing system to all the nodes which want to participate in messaging.

If you cannot install msmq on the client desktop then I would look into making some kind of service call from the client to a service which has NServiceBus on the backend to queue your client call there.